# Variable product attribute: Customizing each displayed radio buttons text value

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations, variable-product

In WooCommerce I am using [*WC Variations Radio Buttons*](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wc-variations-radio-buttons/) plugin *(by 8manos)* to replace the typical dropdown selectors with **Radio Buttons**.

I've added the below code to my child themes `function.php`:

```
// Display the product variation price inside the variations dropdown.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', 'display_price_in_variation_option_name' );

function display_price_in_variation_option_name( $term ) {
    global $wpdb, $product;

    if ( empty( $term ) ) return $term;
    if ( empty( $product->id ) ) return $term;

    $result = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT slug FROM {$wpdb->prefix}terms WHERE name = '$term'" );

    $term_slug = ( !empty( $result ) ) ? $result[0] : $term;

    $query = "SELECT postmeta.post_id AS product_id
                FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS postmeta
                    LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS products ON ( products.ID = postmeta.post_id )
                WHERE postmeta.meta_key LIKE 'attribute_%'
                    AND postmeta.meta_value = '$term_slug'
                    AND products.post_parent = $product->id";

    $variation_id = $wpdb->get_col( $query );

    $parent = wp_get_post_parent_id( $variation_id[0] );




    if ( $parent > 0 ) {
         $_product = new WC_Product_Variation( $variation_id[0] );
         return  '' ."<font size='3' face='Lato'>". wp_kses( woocommerce_price( $_product->get_price() ), array() ) . "<font size='3' color='red' face='Lato' style='normal' weight='300'>".' - ('.$term.')';

    }
    return $term;
}
```

I've been able to style all four variation names just to see if it was possible. **Although, I need each of them to be 4 different colours.** That's where I can use some help.

The image below shows what I want (different colours for each "Option"): 
*Ignore "Color" variation. **Just need to modify the "Tab" variation.***
[image: This is what I want - different colours for each "Option"]

For the moment, the variation name in each of the four radio options is 'red', and I would like a different color for each.

What do I have to change in my code, to achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**2021 Update**

Here is your revisited code that will display **only** around the "Tab" attribute radio buttons custom displayed text a **`<span>`** tag with a different class value based on a combination of the attribute slug and the **`$term_slug`**.

So you will be able to apply some CSS style colors to each radio button displayed custom text for the 'pa_tab' attribute only, adding those CSS rules to your active theme `style.css`…

Here is that revisited code:

```
// Custom function that get the variation id from product attribute option name
function get_variation_id_from_option_name( $term_slug, $taxonomy, $product_id ) {
    global $wpdb;

    return $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "
        SELECT pm.post_id
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta pm
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}posts p ON pm.post_id = p.ID
        WHERE pm.meta_key LIKE '%s'
        AND pm.meta_value = '%s'
        AND p.post_parent = %d
    ", 'attribute_' . $taxonomy, $term_slug, $product_id ) );
}


// Display the product variation price inside the variations dropdown.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', 'display_price_in_variation_option_name' );
function display_price_in_variation_option_name( $option_name ) {
    global $product;

    $taxonomy = 'pa_tab'; // HERE Define the targetted product attribute taxonomy pa_color
    
    $term     = get_term_by( 'name', $option_name, $taxonomy );

    if ( is_admin() || ! is_a( $term, 'WP_Term' ) || ! is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) ) {
        return $option_name;
    }

    $variation_id = get_variation_id_from_option_name( $term->slug, $taxonomy, $product->get_id() );

    if ( $variation_id > 0 ) {
        $variation  = wc_get_product( $variation_id );
        $price_html = wc_price( wc_get_price_to_display( $variation ) );

        if ( has_term( $option_name, $taxonomy, $product->get_id() ) ) {
            $output = ' <span class="'.$taxonomy.'-price">' . strip_tags( $price_html ) . '</span><span class="'.$taxonomy.'-'.$term->slug.'"> - ('.$option_name.')</span>';
        } else {
            $output = ' ' . $option_name;
        }
        return $output;
    }
    return $option_name;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and works.

The generated html code is something like this:

```html
<td class="value">
    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="attribute_pa_color" value="option-blue" id="pa_tab_v_option-blue">
        <label for="pa_tab_v_option-blue"> 
            <span class="pa_tab-price">$99.00</span>
            <span class="pa_tab-option-blue"> - (Option Blue)</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="attribute_pa_color" value="option-green" id="pa_tab_v_option-green">
        <label for="pa_tab_v_option-green"> 
            <span class="pa_tab-price">$299.00</span>
            <span class="pa_tab-option-green"> - (Option Green)</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <!-- ... / ... ... -->                      
</td>
```

---

> So you target this specific radio buttons displayed custom text with CSS rules something like:

```css
span.pa_tab-price {
    font-family: lato, sans-serif; 
    font-size: medium;
}
span.pa_tab-option-blue, span.pa_tab-option-green,
span.pa_tab-option-purple, span.pa_tab-option-orange {
    font-family: lato, sans-serif; 
    font-size: medium;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
}
span.pa_tab-option-blue {
    color: blue;
}
span.pa_tab-option-green {
    color: green;
}
span.pa_tab-option-purple {
    color: purple;
}
span.pa_tab-option-orange {
    color: orange;
}
```

This is just an example

Comment: Thanks for your help @LoicTheAztec. I've replaced the php code I had with what you've come up with. I guess I should

Comment: Sorry, I submitted before finishing my comment. I've replaced the php code I had with what you've come up with. I guess I should've mentioned that I need this on all my products that show these four variations ("Option Blue, Option Green, Option Purple, and Option Orange"). Can you tell me where I need to paste the CSS you've provided.

Pasting the PHP in child-themes functions.php hasn't done anything yet, since I have't pasted the CSS anywhere.