# Woocommerce - Custom price and custom checkout field

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to create a custom checkbox field in my product page, and when it's checked, increase the price of product. Is there any native or plugin way that can do it? 
Which is the best approach to do this?

PS: The product should go to the cart with the new price

Comment: You should better use product variations (variable product) and if you want checkboxes instead of dropdown selector there is a free plugin for that…

Comment: Thank you very much, it's exactly what I was looking for

Comment: In this question the author use the plugin you are looking at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43435329/variable-product-attribute-customizing-each-displayed-radio-buttons-text-value/43437398#43437398